# Is it necessary to have a controller for every JSP page i have?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

While following the Spring MVC architecture is it necessary to have a controller for every jsp i have? For eg. Is it necessary to have a controller for aboutUs or PrivatePolicy or faqs jsp pages(which have static data with them). Can i just have the hyperlink pointing to the next page?

Comment: You can have one controller controlling multiple jsps,

Comment: are you saying that i should have one controller for a header/footer?

Comment: You should have one controller per logical view, for example if it is usermanagement module, you can have multiple jsps (create, edit, search, delete) and you can have one controller controlling each of these view and data around it

Comment: is it safe? does it follows the MVC rule?

Comment: To add to previous answers, it is common to have controllers handle a particular functional area relevant to your domain. For example user management might include registration, password reset, update details, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following in either Spring XML config or Java config, I prefer Java config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class WebHomeConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements
    ApplicationContextAware {

  private ApplicationContext _appContext;


  /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   * 
   * @see
   * org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware#setApplicationContext
   * (org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext)
   */
  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext appContext)
      throws BeansException {
    _appContext = appContext;
  }

  @Bean
  public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
  }


  /**
   * Since we don't have any controller logic, simpler to just define
   * controller for page using View Controller. Note: had to extend
   * WebMvcConfigurerAdapter to get this functionality
   * 
   * @param registry
   */
  @Override
  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
    registry.addViewController("/about").setViewName("aboutUs");
    registry.addViewController("/privacy").setViewName("privacyPolicy");
  }
}
```

Then in your /WEB-INF/views directory you would have the following JSP files:

```
./home.jsp
./aboutUs.jsp
./privacyPolicy.jsp
```

Here are the JSP pages you will then get when hitting these URLs:

```
<baseURL>/ => home.jsp
<baseURL>/about => aboutUs.jsp
<baseURL>/privacy => privacyPolicy.jsp
```

Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

No. Controllers and JSPs are seldom isomorphic. It is frequently a one to many relationship, with one controller coordinating a single "render" from multiple JSPs. Remember, a JSP is ultimately a Servlet and might include other Servlet(s) or JSP(s) (or dispatch, or use a `FilterChain`) to render its response.